# Regex Expression: Capture the Text Between the Lines which includes Newline, Spaces, And Underscore characters

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, uipath

I have some text taken from a pdf file and read into a string:

```
...

Fabric Business Of the Cloths 

4 Description of the property being purchased 
______________________________________________________________________________

...
```

I want to extract the words before the line `4 Description of the property being purchased` and not anything above it or the underscore line below it.

I tried using the regex `/^[^4]*/` but this is returning null.

What would be a suitable regex to achieve the above?

Thanks.

Comment: To use regex, you need to identify some **regular patterns**. With such few information, it's hard to know how you data is composed and what regular patterns could be used. Please, provide a more complete input sample.

Comment: I would read file using StreamReader.  So you want the line immediately after the line with "Fabric Business".  Normally you want to key on lines before the lines you want and not after.

Comment: What do you mean by "which inlcudes Newline" in the title? What does "not anything above it" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex expression works, just remove the / at beginning and end.

EXAMPLE

```
    private void TestRegex()
    {
        string s = "...\n Fabric Business Of the Cloths\n                         4 Description of the property being purchased\n____________________________________________________________________________\n ...";
        Regex regex = new Regex("^[^4]*"); // <--- DO LIKE THIS, PERHAPS.
        //Regex regex = new Regex("/^[^4]*/"); <----NOT THIS
        Match match = regex.Match(s, 0);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
...
 Fabric Business Of the Cloths
```